# Looking for a solution for this IF statement in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

I'm trying to create a IF statement with mySQL...
This is the if in Oracle SQL

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pruef
BEFORE INSERT ON belegung 
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
    counter_1 INTEGER;
    beleg INTEGER;
    max_platz INTEGER;
BEGIN
SELECT :new.kurs_id into beleg from dual;
SELECT COUNT (*) INTO counter_1 FROM belegung WHERE kurs_id = beleg;
SELECT max_personen INTO max_platz FROM KURS WHERE kurs_id = beleg;  
    IF counter_1 >= max_platz THEN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20101, 'Maximale Teilnehmerzahl überschritten');    
    END IF; 
END;
/
```

And this is the mySQL Code

```
delimiter //                
CREATE TRIGGER pruef_mysql  
BEFORE INSERT ON BELEGUNG
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
BEGIN
DECLARE 'counter_1' INT;    
        'beleg' INT;
        'max_platz' INT;
    SELECT new.kurs_id into 'beleg' FROM dual;
    SELECT (*) INTO 'counter_1' FROM 'belegung' WHERE kurs_id=beleg;
    SELECT 'max_personen' INTO 'max_platz' FROM 'KURS' WHERE kurs_id = beleg;  
    IF ('counter_1' >= 'max_platz', signal sqlstate -20101 set msgtext= 'Maximale Teilnehmerzahl überschritten');
    END IF;
    END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I don't know how I do this... Maybe searched on the wrong pages.

Comment: MySQL identifiers do not use `'`; declared variables are not delimited and \` is generally used for field names.

Comment: MySQL has a documentation. You should research on `DECLARE` (there is no block as in PL/SQL), the `IF` control structure (which is almost identical to PL/SQL's), note that there is no `DUAL` in MySQL (unless you've created it) but you can use `SET` or an `SELECT` without a `FROM` clause, check the correct usage of `SIGNAL` again and also take care about the issue Uueerdo mentioned. And probably some more issues. It's hard to believe, that you did any research at all.

Comment: @stickybit I am pretty sure MySQL supports `DUAL`, it's just that it rarely requires it.

Comment: @Uueerdo: You're right `FROM dual`, it's a synonym for like actually nothing in `SELECT`s. But it's no "real" pseudo table like in Oracle.

Comment: @stickybit thank you a lot. The trigger is nearly working. I have problems with the `FROM dual` . But i will get it sooner or later... :)

Answer (score 1):

IF function and IF statement are two different things in MySQL
You want to use the later one 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/if.html